# Span image overlays text but not other images

Tags: css, image, html

I created a thumbnail and description field within a table. The thumbnail has a span image which overlays neighboring text but not neighboring thumbnails??? (all are contained in the #divSparesItem) I've tried adding z-index and display variations to the css as recommended in other discussions but nothing seems to fix the problem. Could anyone help?

HTML:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="Design/Spares Image Thumbnail.png" width="80" height="60" alt="Spare I"/><span><img src="Design/Spares Image Large.png" width="320" height="240" alt="Spare I"/><br/>Spare I</span></a><p>CODE: 123ABC<br/>Description: Donec egestas justo ut nulla congue bibendum.<br/><font color="#FF0000">Price</font></p></td>
                    <td><a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="Design/Spares Image Thumbnail.png" width="80" height="60" alt="Spare I"/><span><img src="Design/Spares Image Large.png" width="320" height="240" alt="Spare II"/><br/>Spare II</span></a><p>CODE: 123ABC<br/>Description: Donec egestas justo ut nulla congue bibendum.<br/><font color="#FF0000">Price</font></p></td>
                    <td><a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="Design/Spares Image Thumbnail.png" width="80" height="60" alt="Spare III"/><span><img src="Design/Spares Image Large.png" width="320" height="240" alt="Spare I"/><br/>Spare III</span></a><p>CODE: 123ABC<br/>Description: Donec egestas justo ut nulla congue bibendum.<br/><font color="#FF0000">Price</font></p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

CSS:

```
#divSparesItem {
    color:#CCC;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:0.8em;
    float:right;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#divSparesItem img {
    float:left;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-left:#000;
    border-top:#000;
    border-right:#999;
    border-bottom:#999;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}

.thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}

.thumbnail span{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#333;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    border-left:#999;
    border-top:#999;
    border-right:#000;
    border-bottom:#000;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    visibility:hidden;
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.thumbnail span img{
    border:none;
    z-index:100;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    background-color:#333;
    top:-115px;
    left:0;
}
```

You can see the issue [here](http://www.synte.co.za/Puzey/Spares.html) (click on the Benelli1 tab). Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't really be using a table for this layout - you should simply be using tags such as DIVs. HTML tables are really only meant to display tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is make two [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) here. The first is the document root stacking context, which contains that `table`. The other will be created by the absolutely positioned `span` once we give it a `z-index`. Once we do that, all we need to do is make sure that it's on top of the other stacking context, like so:

CSS:

```
.thumbnail:hover span {
    ...
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7HzN/) that shows it displaying properly in all major browsers. I had to mess up the `css` a bit for the `.thumbnail:hover span` selector for the JSFiddle to display properly.

Also, while the conceptual understanding of `z-index` is a no-brainer, actually putting it to use in a document can be a bit challenging if you haven't read up on how it works. If `z-index` keeps causing you trouble, then I recommend you read through the different pages on the link I sent you if `z-index`. You'll become a pro in no time!

Comment: Haha thanks jmeas & Kraz, my eagerness to force everything to adhere to the z-index caused me a big headache for such a simple problem. Works perfect now and thanks again, you guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the z-index from .thumbnails :

```
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 25;*/
}
```

Just don't add z-index everywhere. :)